# Mixing variable in string after a function call in PHP

Tags: php

I want to mix a variable after call a function, but not when I set the variable.

*My example code:*

```
<?php

$greeting = "hi! {$gbye}";

function greetings() {
    global $greeting;
    $gbye = "goodbye!";
    return $greeting;
}

echo greetings();

?>
```

**Fiddle:** http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/kd5w-p7q4

I tried escaping the $ symbol: \$, but this only gives me the complete text. And replacing the escaped symbol make the same.

The `$gbye` variable is inside a language file, by this reason, I have to save the word (`$gbye`) until I call the function (to replace it as if the full string (`$greeting = "hi! {$gbye}";`) was inside the function). It's just an example.

So what can I do?

Comment: not going to tell you how, as its almost always bad practice to use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: @dagon. I agree. There is way to do it. But there is also more simple way to achieve the same result.

Comment: I made an edit specifying what I want to achieve ;)

Comment: `$greeting = "hi! ".$gbye;` will work just fine as long as the variable is in scope

Comment: `E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined variable: gbye -- at line 3`; Fiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/yhvv-6cj4

Comment: **"as long as the variable is in scope"** seems your only problem is understanding [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score 0):

For language file usage, you may want to use your own meta keyword, instead of php variable syntax. This is ensure what you want to do is seperated from what PHP wants to do. This will save you from future bugs and maintenance effort. For example,

```
<?php

$greeting = "hi! #gbye#";

function greetings() {
    global $greeting;
    return str_replace("#gbye#", "goodbye!", $greeting);
}

echo greetings();

?>
```

Comment: Because it's not as easy as that... The `$gbye` variable is inside a language file, by this reason, I have to save the word (`$gbye`) until I call the function (to replace it as if the full string (`$greeting = "hi! {$gbye}";`) was inside the function).

It's just an example. ;)